# Manipulate with plot and images

Tags: manipulate

I have the following code:

```
ClearAll[rt1, rt2]
rt1 = Transpose@
    RecurrenceTable[{o[n] == 0.88 o[n - 1] + 0.36 e[n - 1] + 30,
      e[n] == 0.64 e[n - 1] + 0.11 h[n - 1],
      h[n] == 0.89 h[n - 1] + 30,
      o[0] == 2400, e[0] == 1800, h[0] == 3500}, {o, e, h}, {n, 
      0, #}] &;
Row[ListPlot[#@50, BaseStyle -> PointSize[Medium], ImageSize -> 500, 
    PlotLegends -> {"Pollutants: L. Ontario", "Pollutants: L. Erie", 
      "Pollutants: L. Huron"}] & /@ {rt1}]
```

[image]

which plots the discrete dynamical system modeling pollution in the some lakes.

[image]

What I'd like to do, is to present the `DiscretePlot` described above, along with the map of the the lakes, and use `Manipulate` to control the time steps showing how the system changes with time.
As I move the slider, I'd like circles in the respective lakes to change size showing the amount of pollution in each lake, as such:

[image]

Is it possible to accomplish this with `Manipulate`? My graphics skills with *Mathematica* are very basic, and thus far I have not been able to make anything work.

Could someone at least point towards a template I might be able to modify to accomplish this? Much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: So basically you would like to the the circles and the number in them changing as the `Manipulate` slider moves?

Comment: Yes! But the discrete plot above should change with it as well.

Comment: Of that, I am not sure.

Comment: So you mean a point on the discrete plot would be highlighted as well as the time changes?

Comment: Either that, or the plot itself would be "building" itself as time progresses. I haven't been able to accomplish any.

Comment: That's very close. The main problem I'm having is that I cannot make work with the original plot. I also just get one circle as opposed to one in every lake :(    I suppose my ambitions are much greater than my technical skills hehe.  Thanks a lot Oska!

Comment: Is there a way to make the circles change size in proportion to the values inside them?  Also, why would the circle for Lake Ontario not show up? When I try to fix All I get is text over the plot. Would you post it as an answer so that I may give you credit? You have been both a gentleman and a scholar Oska. Eternally grateful.

Comment: There you go, I was too lazy to make it a proper answer until now )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pretty rough solution, you should be able to make it look better but here is the idea. I put the `pos` on random lakes, put them where ever you wish.

```
i = Import@"https://i.stack.imgur.com/JL5No.png";
pos1 = {500, 300}; 
pos2 = {320, 160}; 
nmax = 50;
Manipulate[
 Column[{
  First[ListPlot[(#@50)[[All, 1 ;; n]], BaseStyle -> PointSize[Medium],
          ImageSize -> 350, PlotRange -> {{0, nmax + 1}, {0, Max@rt1@500 + 1}}] & /@ {rt1}],
  Show[{i, 
   Graphics[{Opacity@.5, FaceForm@Red, 
    {Disk[#, 5*Log@((rt1@50)[[#2, n]])],
     Text[(rt1@50)[[#2, n]], #]} & @@@ Thread@{{pos1, pos2}, {1, 2}}}]}]},
 Alignment -> Center], {n, 1, nmax, 1}]
```

[image]

You should play with the `Disk` size to make it more accurate, my answer is just here to show you how it could be done.

Comment: For some reason I cannot get the thing to add the 3rd circle. I should have one for every plot line. Many thanks.

Comment: Nevermind. I got it!

Comment: @JohnWayne360 Good :) Just need to add a new `pos` and `{1, 2, 3}` :)